# Error handler returning default value, when using async/await

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, async-await, angular7

There is a proposed error handler in the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling), which is able to return a default value to the caller in the case of an error.

```ts
/**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

Now I have a webservice call using async/await:

```ts
public async getItemsAsync() {
    try {
      return await this.http.get<string[]>("/some/url").toPromise();
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.handleError<string[]>('getItemsAsync', []);
    }
}
```

What do I have to change to be able to return a default value from my error handler?

```ts
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {  
    console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return result as T;
}
```

Should I return an `Observable` or a `Promise`? I tried both, but it didn't compile. Currently, `string[]` isn't returned. I only get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider handling the error at the observable level:

```
async getItemsAsync() {
    return await this.http
      .get<string[]>("/some/url")
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<string[]>("getItemsAsync", [])))
      .toPromise();
}
```

You can use the `catchError` operator from RxJS. This will run your error logging and and return an observable of the value you specify to the `handleError` function. Then your `toPromise` operator converts either the error observable or the value from your api response to a promise.

Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-error-handler)

Comment: Is it possible to get the correct `HttpErrorResponse` object? Before I passed `error` to `handleError()` and could check for the status code. Now I only get `0` as the status code.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do, you have the correct `HttpErrorResponse` in the `handleError` callback. The variable `error` in the callback is the HttpErrorResponse

Comment: Thanks. It must have to do with the response from the backend, which lead to the strange result (got 401 and *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* error in the console, but `handleError` got a general error). With the new *wrong* data it seems to work and I get the correct `HttpErrorResponse`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll have to finish my modification and afterwards I'll mark it.